# Upload file to mailgun server with swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, mailgun

I am trying to attach file to Mailgun. Here is my curl command:

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-XXX'
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox---.mailgun.org/messages     
-F from='Excited User<mailgun@sandbox---.mailgun.org>'     
-F to=mail@gmail.com     
-F subject='Hello'     
-F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' 
-F attachment='@/Users/.../mytestfile.jpeg'
```

Result: Ok, the file has been attached to the message and been successfully transferred.

After that, I tried doing it with `URLRequest`:

```
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "domru", withExtension: "jpeg") else {
        print(">>>can't find path")
        return
    }      
    let parameters: HTTPHeaders = [
        "from": "Excited User<mailgun@sandbox---.mailgun.org>",
        "to": "mail@gmail.com",
        "subject": "hello",
        "text": "my text message" ]

    let data = encodeRequest(parameters: parameters, attachment: filePath)
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox---.mailgun.org/messages")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = data.data(using: .utf8)
    request.addValue("Basic \(credentialData!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:{(data, response, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err)
        }
        if let response = response {
            print("url = \(response.url!)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }

    })
    task.resume()

    private func encodeRequest(parameters:[String:String], attachment: URL) -> String {
    var result = ""
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        result.append("\(key)="+"\(value)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)! + "&")
    }
    result.append("attachment="+attachment.path.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!)
    return result
    }
```

Result: The text of the message has been delivered, but the file has not been attached.

I also tried to solve that with Alamofire:

```
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named:"domru.jpeg")!, 1)

    let header : HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization":"Basic \(credentialData!)"]

    Alamofire.upload(
        // parameters are the same as in the previous part of code
        multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
            multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "domru", fileName: "domru.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        },
        to: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox---.mailgun.org/messages",
        method: .post,
        headers: header,
        encodingCompletion: { (result) in
            debugPrint(result)
        }
```

Result the same: The attachment has not been attached to the message.

How attach a file to a message in this case?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still working on this. It seems that the MailGun API looks for the name to be attachment on each of the attachments included so this line:

```
multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "domru", fileName: "domru.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

would need to be changed to:

```
multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "attachment", fileName: "domru.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

not sure if that entirely fixes it